# Rails - Form_for error for undefined local variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, variables

I've been trying to setup a contact form but I keep getting errors and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The latest error I'm getting is:

```
NameError in Contacts#new
Showing .../app/views/contacts/new.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined local variable or method `contact' for #<#<Class:0x007fa2933ca1f8>:0x007fa29a4df460>
Did you mean?  @contact
           concat
Extracted source (around line #2):
1
2
3
4
5
6

<h1>Contact us</h1>
<%= form_for(contact) do |f| %>
  <div class="field entry_box">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control entry_field" %>
</div>
```

My ContactsController

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @contact = Contact.new
end

def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
    redirect_to contacts_path, notice: "Thanks for contacting us!"
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private

def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :message)
end

end
```

Model

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Routes (relevant parts)

```
resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]

get "contact" =>'contacts#new'
post "contact" =>'contacts#create'
```

View (new.html.erb)

```
<h1>Contact us</h1>
<%= form_for(contact) do |f| %>
  <div class="field entry_box">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control entry_field" %>
</div>

<div class="field entry_box">
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.number_field :email, class: "form-control entry_field" %>
</div>

<div class="field entry_box">
  <%= f.label :message %>
  <%= f.text_field :message, class: "form-control entry_field" %>
</div>

<div class="actions center space_big">
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-lg btn-success" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller defines an instance variable,  `@contact`, but your view uses `contact`. There's a difference - make sure your `form_for` call uses the `@contact` variable that your controller defines.

You have:

```
<%= form_for(contact) do |f| %>
```

which you should change to

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
```

because of this line in your controller

```
@contact = Contact.new
```

In most errors, Rails will give you the source code and line number that caused the exception, and will then give you a hint - in this case, it says "did you mean `@contact`?"

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. I suppose I was stuck as I have another form that isn't using the @variable name and it works fine. Couldn't quite work that out :/

Comment: @Stephen Try to keep your naming conventions consistent to avoid issues like this - I try to always use an instance variable for forms, where possible.

Comment: Thank you @ArtOfCode, I'll do that!

Comment: @Stephen, The distinguishing factor between what you observed in another form that does not have the `@` is that that other form is a partial.  When you run `rails g scaffold [model_name]`, the default scaffold code includes a file called `_form.html.erb`.  Instead of all of the actual form code (with the inputs, etc.) being contained the `new.html.erb` file, the form code is in the `_form.html.erb` partial file and the `new.html.erb` file probably has something like:  `<%= render 'form', widget: @widget %>
`

Answer (score 1):

The variable `contact` is `undefined` in `new.html.erb`. See the suggestion made by rails to use `@contact`?

The line

```
<%= form_for(contact) do |f| %>
```

should be

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
```

The instance variable `@contact` is passed on to the view from the `new` action of `ContactsController`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write instance variable in new form just write

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sry i mean instance variable